# Black lines appear on UISearchBar as it dismisses

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I have a standard grey UISearchDisplayController. When I press cancel on the active search, as it moves down and unhides the nav bar, it shows a weird flickering set of horizontal black lines as it goes inactive. I've messed with the opaque/translucent settings with no success. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9NyT.png)

Answer (score 0):

i must not have my views set up right. this fixed the problem:

```
- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return nil;
}
```